# How to simulate keyboard keys in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on my grad project, its an autopilot and I am making the plane in unity and all the machine learning stuff in python, the python code will return only what the plane will do "up, down, left, right, enginepower up,...) and the c# code will take care of all the physics and so on,  so I want to simulate that if (left) then the computer will press (A).

I've tried inputsimulator but that's all.

```
string t = GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer; // this will get the input from python

if (t=="left") // if what the neural network choose is left do this
{
    //what I need to convert the "left" to an actual keyboard press to
    //be used by the crossplatformmanager
}
float roll = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
```

I expect that:

```
if (t=="left")
{ 
    keyboardbutton="A" 
}
```

and that `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis` will treat it as if i physically pressed the key.

Comment: Interesting project !
But it's not completely clear for me : You are trying to get the python to govern the plane (make it go up or down, etc...), and then use that in the unity 3D engine to visualize it, right ? So why do you need to export the inputs in C# to python ? Isn't it the other way around ?

Comment: afaik you can not cause a system wide keyboard event from within Unity but you could use a local socket connection to pass commands to the python script (if that one listens on the socket). If something within Unity itself should happen why not simply adding it inside that `if`? In other words: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: or (only on windows) you could try [Windows Input Simulator](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=inputsimulator)

Comment: Have you stumbled upon the [Unity help forums](https://answers.unity.com/questions/28473/simulating-key-presses.html)?
[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/2xm5j1/press_keys_via_script/) also has something to say on the matter. 
In particular you might find this [suggestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a XY problem, usually input simulation is need for program that is out of your control, because you can't access the code directly. But for your question both python and unity project are written by yourself, so you don't need simulate the input, just call the method.

For example, if you wanna roll something by horizontal axis input, you may do:

```
var h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
Roll(h);
```

Then if the value is from the clipboard:

```
float h;
string t = GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer;
switch(t) {
   case "left": h = -1f; break;
   case "right": h = 1f; break;
   ....
}
Roll(h);
```

Comment: this is a progress than what i did for sure but this will mean that the rotation will be either hard left or hard right which is not ideal for flying a plane so i will take this and try making it as increments h+=0.01 for each time step that the computer presses the button, but really thank you for your help